# make one row from multiple rows oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, row

I'm using Oracle 11g and I have a little problem over here, I hope someone can help me.

When I do execute my query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable;
```

The result is:

```
     ID     |     VER     |     DATE
 -----------+-------------+--------------
    120     |      1      |   01/03/14
    120     |      2      |   02/03/14
    120     |      3      |   04/03/14

    110     |      1      |   01/03/14

    130     |      1      |   02/03/14
    130     |      2      |   11/03/14
```

I need something like this:

```
    ID   |   VER   |   DATE   |   VER2   |   DATE2   |   VER3   |   DATE3
---------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------
   120   |    1    | 01/03/14 |    2     | 02/03/14  |     3    | 04/03/14
   110   |    1    | 01/03/14 |          |           |          | 
   130   |    1    | 02/03/14 |    2     | 11/03/14  |          |
```

Also at some point I'll need to `SUM` or rest `DATE3 - DATE2` and/or `DATE2 - DATE1`.

Kind newbie in this forum, still don't know how it works, hope I made my self clear.

Someone told to use `CASE` and `DECODE` but honestly SQL isn't my strongest area.

thanks.

Comment: Do you know that there will never be more than 3 rows in the table for a particular `id` value?  If you added a 4th row with an `id` of 120 and `ver` of 4, what would that do to the expected output?

Comment: There will be up to 5 rows for the same id value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform it in Oracle 11g using pivot function

```
 WITH TABLE1(ID, VER, DDATE) AS (
 select 120     ,      1      ,   '01/03/14' from dual union all
 select 120     ,      2      ,   '02/03/14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 select 120     ,      3      ,   '04/03/14' from dual union all
 select 110     ,      1      ,   '01/03/14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 select 130     ,      1      ,   '02/03/14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 130     ,      2      ,   '11/03/14' FROM DUAL) 
 ------------
 ---- End of Data
 ------------
 SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE1
PIVOT (MIN(VER) AS VER, MIN(DDATE) FOR VER IN (1 as DATE1, 2 as DATE2, 3 as DATE3, 4 as DATE4, 5 as DATE5));
```

In prior version of oracle, you can use case and min

```
 WITH TABLE1(ID, VER, DDATE) AS (
 select 120     ,      1      ,   '01/03/14' from dual union all
 select 120     ,      2      ,   '02/03/14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 select 120     ,      3      ,   '04/03/14' from dual union all
 select 110     ,      1      ,   '01/03/14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 select 130     ,      1      ,   '02/03/14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 130     ,      2      ,   '11/03/14' FROM DUAL) 
 ------------
 ---- End of Data
 ------------
 SELECT ID, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 1 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 1 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) AS DDATE1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 2 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 2 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) as DDATE2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 3 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 3 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) as DDATE3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 4 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER5,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 4 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) as DDATE4,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 5 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER6,
        min(case when ver = 5 then DDATE else null end) as DDATE5
  FROM TABLE1
group by id;
```

Output in Both Cases is

```
|  ID | VER1 |   DDATE1 |   VER2 |   DDATE2 |   VER3 |   DDATE3 |   VER5 | DDATE4 |   VER6 | DDATE5 |
|-----|------|----------|--------|----------|--------|----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 120 |    1 | 01/03/14 |      2 | 02/03/14 |      3 | 04/03/14 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 110 |    1 | 01/03/14 | (null) |   (null) | (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 130 |    1 | 02/03/14 |      2 | 11/03/14 | (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

For your table, you can use

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM <your table_name>
PIVOT (MIN(VER) AS VER, MIN(DDATE) FOR VER IN (1 as DATE1, 2 as DATE2, 3 as DATE3, 4 as DATE4, 5 as DATE5));
```

or

```
 SELECT ID, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 1 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 1 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) AS DDATE1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 2 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 2 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) as DDATE2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 3 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 3 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) as DDATE3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 4 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER5,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 4 THEN DDATE ELSE NULL END) as DDATE4,
        MIN(CASE WHEN VER = 5 THEN VER ELSE NULL END) AS VER6,
        min(case when ver = 5 then DDATE else null end) as DDATE5
  FROM <your_table_name>
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you San, it totally worked, but the table has changed, now there is another column; STATUS, status can be 'A', 'C', 'R' or NULL, I make it work with CASE and MIN, but haven't got luck with PIVOT, could you help a little more please? (As the prior example I would need STATUS1, STATUS2, STATUS3, STATUS4, STATUS5 each with his own value, I would like to use PIVOT it's seems more pro and clean).

Comment: Finally found it; PIVOT (MIN(VER) AS VER, MIN(DDATE) AS DATE, MAX(STATUS) AS STATUS FOR VERSION IN (1 DATE1, 2 as DATE2, 3 as DATE3, 4 as DATE4, 5 as DATE5)), thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you'll only ever have a small, finite number of versions, [you could do it this way (SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f1b5/27/0)

```
  WITH VER1 AS (SELECT * FROM version_data WHERE version = 1)
     , VER2 AS (SELECT * FROM version_data WHERE version = 2)
     , VER3 AS (SELECT * FROM version_data WHERE version = 3)
     , VER4 AS (SELECT * FROM version_data WHERE version = 4)
     , VER5 AS (SELECT * FROM version_data WHERE version = 5)
SELECT DISTINCT(t.version_id) AS "VERSION_ID",
       ver1.version AS "VER1",
       ver1.version_date AS "VER1_DATE",
       ver2.version AS "VER2",
       ver2.version_date AS "VER2_DATE",
       ver3.version AS "VER3",
       ver3.version_date AS "VER3_DATE",
       ver4.version AS "VER4",
       ver5.version_date AS "VER4_DATE",
       ver5.version AS "VER5",
       ver5.version_date AS "VER5_DATE"
  FROM version_data t
  LEFT JOIN VER1 ver1 ON ver1.version_id = t.version_id
  LEFT JOIN VER2 ver2 ON ver2.version_id = t.version_id
  LEFT JOIN VER3 ver3 ON ver3.version_id = t.version_id
  LEFT JOIN VER4 ver4 ON ver4.version_id = t.version_id
  LEFT JOIN VER5 ver5 ON ver5.version_id = t.version_id
 ORDER BY t.version_id
;
```